# How to retrieve the apply method of a case class

Tags: scala

Given a case class, I want to retrieve the apply method.

I can do `A.apply _` but is there a way to retrieve it only with A

Example

```
scala> case class A(s: String)
defined class A

scala> def f[B, C](h: B => C) = h
f: [B, C](h: B => C)B => C

scala> f(A.apply _)
res0: String => A = <function1>
```

Is it possible to just write `f(A)` or something like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me in Scala 2.11:

```
package sandbox

object ApplyMethod {
  import sandbox.OtherApplyTest.C
  case class A(s: String)

  object B {
    def apply(s: String): A = A(s)
  }

  def D(s: String) = OtherApplyTest.D(s)

  def f[T](h: String => T) = h("hello")

  def g[T, U](h: T => U) = h

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println(f(A)) // prints A(hello)
    // println(f(B)) doesn't compile
    println(f(C)) // prints C(hello)
    println(f(D)) // prints D(hello)
    println(g(A)) // prints A
    println(g(C)) // prints C
    println(g(D)) // prints <function1>
    println(f(g(A))) // prints A(hello)
  }
}

object OtherApplyTest {

  case class C(s: String)

  case class D(s: String)
}
```

Looks like what you want to do (and also how you did it) Could be that it does not work in REPL or in an older Scala version.

Answer (score 2):

I've never run into a situation where Scala considers the `A(...)` any differently from `A.apply(...)`. In my interpreter, `f(A)` works just fine:

```
scala> case class A(s: String)
defined class A

scala> def f[B, C](h: B => C) = h
f: [B, C](h: B => C)B => C

scala> f(A)
res1: String => A = A
```